# SAP/Excel: Importing SAP VB(7 output into an Excel file

Tags: sap

I'm trying to use excel to analyze the output of SAP tcode VB(7 (Settlement of Rebate Agreements, but set to "Only issue sales revenue", effectively creating a report of all rebate agreements and their sales volumes). [screenshot of SAP VB(7 output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rda33.png)

The issue is, this is a rather old transaction in SAP from the times back when reports were sent to matrix printers rather than processed digitally. Limited horizontal room means the program goes ahead and splits what we would consider a single record into multiple rows - see screenshot linked.

There’s two sets of information being presented; the heading marked in red corresponds to the data marked in red, and the header marked in blue corresponds to the individual rows of data, being split up over two lines.

It gets even worse: The data in the second red bracket defines what fields can be present on the blue brackets, and so there will be blocks of data in such exports where the actual columns present in the blue blocks of one red block are different from the columns in the blue blocks of another red block. Lastly, the .txt export (which is basically just the spool that would be fed to a printer) repeats headers per page, meaning on the export, detail data will be interrupted by repeated headers on page breaks.

Does anyone have experience with processing such a file into excel? I am barely familiar with PowerQuery, but I wouldn't even know how to tackle this. Is PowerQuery a good choice, or should I be looking into other tools? I'd be thankful for every bit of help!